# Why emojis are not appearing in Google's SERP when being added into the <title>?

Tags: search-results, title, title-attribute

I would like to know what it takes to use emojis in Google's SERP.

Here's how an example result shows up:
[image]

And here's the code behind that:

[image]

Now, as you can see, the title and description have emojis, but Google won't show them.

Any reason why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google lists their guidelines for this [here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/favicon-in-search) and state

> If your site has a favicon, it can be included in Google Search
> results for your site

Your code looks compliant with their guidelines.  The only thing I can't see is the size of your icon which must be `a multiple of 48px square, for example: 48x48px, 96x96px, 144x144px and so on`.

However, they also state `

> favicon isn't guaranteed in search results even if all guidelines are
> met.

`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm referring to the emojis added to a title, not to the page favicon. Do the same rules apply? How can I set the size of an emoji inside <title>? Thanks!!

Comment: @Rosamunda, see modification "If your site has a favicon, it can be included in Google Search results for your site"  You can also see an example in the Google doc.